# Things to check for with a orthogonal matrix or vector

Tags: linear-algebra

What are there different rules you need to check for with an orthogonal matrix or vector? Why does an orthogonal matrix need to nxn but a orthogonal vector does not?

$$\begin{bmatrix}
1\\ 
0\\ 
1\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}
0\\ 
1\\
0\end{bmatrix}$$

dot product
1*0 + 0 * 1 + 1 *0 = 0

What else do I need to check for besides dot product with a matrix? Why does this have to be nxn?

\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0\\ 0 & 1\\ 1 & 0
\end{bmatrix}

dot product
1*0 + 0 * 1 + 1 *0 = 0

What else do I need to check for besides dot product with a vector?

What about one like this? Why is this not orthogonal?

\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 1\\ 1 & -1
\end{bmatrix}

dot product 1*1 + 1 * -1 = 0

Comment: No…orthogonal matrix is something different. You know what a orthogonal vector is. A orthogonal matrix, however, is a matrix such that its transpose is its inverse and is a completely different concept

Comment: If it isn't a square matrix, then it doesn't make sense to talk about inverse. Although the name "orthogonal matrix" is misleading, just stick to the definition and study what is the use of such kind of matrix.

Comment: @LiChunMin It’s not a *completely* different concept. The columns/rows of an orthogonal matrix are pairwise orthogonal.

Comment: True. Thanks for the remark. I should have established this relationship in my previous comment.

Comment: This is rather important since if you get enough orthogonal vectors, you get a orthogonal basis. If normalize each and form a matrix, it is a orthogonal matrix with the aforementioned desired property.

Comment: @LiChunMin Why is the one at the bottom not orthogonal?

Comment: @amd Why is the one at the bottom not orthogonal?

Comment: $Q^TQ$ is not $I$. You need to normalize both row/column vector to have it match the definition.

Answer (score 0):

A matrix whose columns are orthonormal vectors is called an Orthogonal matrix.  If A is orthogonal, you can verify by multiplication that AT*A is identity, where AT is A transposed.  This is true even if A is rectangular.  But A*AT is not identity.  If A is square then A*AT is also identity and then Ainverse=AT

Comment: This is a good answer, but please use MathJax to format mathematical expressions. You can find a basic tutorial [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).